# Autorotation with navigation back button

Tags: xcode, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, orientation

I am creating an app which support all orientation.
I am using navigationController here.
for orientation i am using this code

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:
(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait 
    || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{
    category1.frame = CGRectMake(54, 68, 190, 174);
    category2.frame = CGRectMake(291, 68, 190, 174);
    category3.frame = CGRectMake(525, 68, 190, 174);
    category4.frame = CGRectMake(54, 296, 190, 174);
    category5.frame = CGRectMake(291, 296, 190, 174);
    category6.frame = CGRectMake(525, 296, 190, 174);
    category7.frame = CGRectMake(54, 527, 190, 174);
    category8.frame = CGRectMake(291, 527, 190, 174);
    category9.frame = CGRectMake(525, 527, 190, 174);
    category10.frame = CGRectMake(291, 757, 190, 174);
    extra1.frame = CGRectMake(80, 781, 138, 125);
    extra2.frame = CGRectMake(551, 781, 138, 125);

}
else 
{
    category1.frame = CGRectMake(61, 50, 190, 174);
    category2.frame = CGRectMake(298, 50, 190, 174);
    category3.frame = CGRectMake(537, 50, 190, 174);
    category4.frame = CGRectMake(774, 50, 190, 174);
    category5.frame = CGRectMake(61, 278, 190, 174);
    category6.frame = CGRectMake(298, 278, 190, 174);
    category7.frame = CGRectMake(537, 278, 190, 174);
    category8.frame = CGRectMake(774, 278, 190, 174);
    category9.frame = CGRectMake(298, 509, 190, 174);
    category10.frame = CGRectMake(537, 509, 190, 174);
    extra1.frame = CGRectMake(80, 533, 120, 125);
    extra2.frame = CGRectMake(800, 533, 120, 125);

}

}
```

It works perfectly in this view. when i tab button it goes to secondviewcontroller where i am showing tableview.
But , if i go back to the firstview via navigation back button ,the orientation is not showing perfectly.
Above code is not working for navigation back button.

What should i do for this problem??
Any suggestion ??

Thank you in advance.

Edited:

I have removed my above function from firstview and copy the code to this function.

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait 
    || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{
    category1.frame = CGRectMake(54, 68, 190, 174);
    category2.frame = CGRectMake(291, 68, 190, 174);
    category3.frame = CGRectMake(525, 68, 190, 174);
    category4.frame = CGRectMake(54, 296, 190, 174);
    category5.frame = CGRectMake(291, 296, 190, 174);
    category6.frame = CGRectMake(525, 296, 190, 174);
    category7.frame = CGRectMake(54, 527, 190, 174);
    category8.frame = CGRectMake(291, 527, 190, 174);
    category9.frame = CGRectMake(525, 527, 190, 174);
    category10.frame = CGRectMake(291, 757, 190, 174);
    extra1.frame = CGRectMake(80, 781, 138, 125);
    extra2.frame = CGRectMake(551, 781, 138, 125);

}
else 
{
    category1.frame = CGRectMake(61, 50, 190, 174);
    category2.frame = CGRectMake(298, 50, 190, 174);
    category3.frame = CGRectMake(537, 50, 190, 174);
    category4.frame = CGRectMake(774, 50, 190, 174);
    category5.frame = CGRectMake(61, 278, 190, 174);
    category6.frame = CGRectMake(298, 278, 190, 174);
    category7.frame = CGRectMake(537, 278, 190, 174);
    category8.frame = CGRectMake(774, 278, 190, 174);
    category9.frame = CGRectMake(298, 509, 190, 174);
    category10.frame = CGRectMake(537, 509, 190, 174);
    extra1.frame = CGRectMake(80, 533, 120, 125);
    extra2.frame = CGRectMake(800, 533, 120, 125);

}

    return YES;
 }
```

in my second view controller i have done

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {

    return YES;
 }
```

When i go back to the firstview by tapping navigation back button **else condition**(landscape mode) works fine but i don't know why it is not working with **if condition**(Portraitmode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write all this code in the following function.

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {
        //set all the frames according to the current interface orientation
        return YES;
 }
```

NEW EDIT :

Write this method into your detailviewcontroller.m file

```
  - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
  {
        UIViewController *controller = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        [controller shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];

        return YES;
  }
```

Comment: Then it should work. When you come back to this viewController, it is responding to this method right?

Comment: turn off AutoResize Subviews from nib of this ViewController.

Comment: this solution is work only for landscape mode.. Any idea why??

Comment: this will have to work for all the orientations. You must be setting the frames wrongly. Check if they are placed properly and try debugging this method. Post how you doing it with the method i suggested.

Comment: I just tried it myselves. Its working fine. Just keep a breakpoint in the portrait section and print nslogs in that to get somewhat idea of what's going on.

Comment: btw, what happens in portrait mode exactly?

Comment: when i tap back button nslog not showing text "portrait mode" and in portrait mode my three buttons are disable because of previous position of landscapemode.

Comment: You have written this code in a UIViewController.m file right? Navigation controller wont be doing any problem here.

Comment: Ya.. but its not taking portraitview's condition.. msg prints after coming back in landscape mode but not when coming back to portrait mode.. If you can then please try it after taking navigationviewcontroller.. And thanks for helping..!!

Comment: It should have worked, don't know what problem is occurring. Mail me the code if possible.